# Autofill Password management

Tags: synchronization, icloud

I just design an app that manage user password UI. And i was told third party app cannot be given permission to autofill password . So my question  is Can third party password management app suggest login details while logining in into a website?** If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a third party app can provide passwords to apps (such as Safari) using the [Autofill Credential Provider Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/721/). See also [Authentication Services Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices).